# Why is the framebuffer texture completley blank?

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, framebuffer

I have this problem, where I have 2 framebuffers. And I draw to a different one each frame. So on the first frame it would be the first framebuffer, then the second, then the first again and so on. But for some reason, whenever I try to access this texture, it is completly blank. I made a simplified program with this same issue. In a shader, each pixel gets a random value on the first frame. It then draws this to a framebuffer, where it should draw the next thing into the other frame buffer, then back into the first frame buffer, and it should avarage the pixels out over time, to a grayish color. But what really happens is the first frame is bright, and the next frames are dark as the frame buffer object's texture is black, so it just halves the color.

I tried several things, first I tried having seperate variables for the first and second fbos, but that changed nothing. Then I tried creating the fbo variables in the for loop, the glGen functions. Then for some reason I kept getting an invalid operation error with a flashing red and black screen, so I reverted some changes and thats where I am at now. Here is the code for the simplified program. This isn't the real program, this is just a recreation of the bug.

Creating the framebuffers:

```
GLuint fbo[2], fbotex[2], rbo[2];

glGenFramebuffers(2, fbo);
glGenTextures(2, fbotex);
glGenRenderbuffers(2, rbo);

for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo[i]);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, fbotex[i]);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, SCR_WIDTH * 2, SCR_HEIGHT * 2, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, fbotex[i], 0);

    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, rbo[i]);
    glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8, SCR_WIDTH * 2, SCR_HEIGHT * 2);
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, 0);

    glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, rbo[i]);

    if (glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
    {
        std::cout << "ERROR::FRAMEBUFFER:: Framebuffer is not complete! " << glGetError() << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }
}

glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
```

Drawing the random pixels:

```
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo[buffer]);

glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
renderShader.use();
renderShader.setInt("width", SCR_WIDTH);
renderShader.setInt("height", SCR_HEIGHT);
renderShader.setInt("frame", frame);
renderShader.setInt("last", fbotex[1 - buffer]);

// std::cout << buffer << std::endl;;

glBindVertexArray(renderVAO);

glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);

glUseProgram(0);

glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);

glBindFramebuffer(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo[buffer]);

glBlitFramebuffer(0, 0, SCR_WIDTH * 2, SCR_HEIGHT * 2, 0, 0, SCR_WIDTH * 2, SCR_HEIGHT * 2, GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT, GL_NEAREST);

glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
```

The fragment shader:

```
#version 330 core

out vec4 col;
in vec2 puv;

uniform sampler2D last;
uniform int width;
uniform int height;
uniform int frame;

float random(inout int seed)
{
    seed = seed * 747796405 + 289133653;
    int res = ((seed >> ((seed >> 28) + 4)) ^ seed) * 277803737;
    res = (res >> 22) ^ res;
    return res / 4294967295.0f + 0.5f;
}

void main()
{
    ivec2 pixel = ivec2(puv * vec2(width, height));

    int id = pixel.y * width + pixel.x;

    int seed = id + frame * 59082;

    vec3 oldCol = texture(last, puv).xyz;
    vec3 c = vec3(random(seed), random(seed), random(seed));

    if (frame == 0) col = vec4(c, 1);
    else col = vec4((c + oldCol) / 2, 1);
}
```